# Flutter update list items with delay

Tags: flutter

I have list of items that are loading from database, the problem is each one of this items require to get 1 string loaded from server and I can't find out a way to make that string get updates.

**Logic**

1. Show list of locations from database (done)
2. Show each item current time (the issue)

**Screenshot**

[image: one]

**Code** `Commented`

```
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.0, horizontal: 4.0),
    child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: locations.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            WorldTime instance = WorldTime(name: locations[index].name, country: locations[index].country, wikipedia: locations[index].wikipedia, location: locations[index].location, flag: locations[index].flag);


            // need to use await but async/await is not allowed under `Widget build(BuildContext context)`
            instance.getTime();
            var time = instance.time;
            return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () {},
                    title: Text('${locations[index].location}'),
                    subtitle: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                        Text(locations[index].country),
                        SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                        Text('$time'), // <-- show updated time (currently only show first load `null` and never gets updated).
                    ],
                    ),
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/${locations[index].flag}'),
                    ),
                ),
                );
        },
    ),
),
```

`PS:` Regarding to `instance.getTime()` in case you doubt that problem might be from there, I need to assure you that `instance.getTime()` works absolutely fine in all other screens that I have and here is console log screenshot of it in this particular list items which proves the data are loaded but not show in view (it loads after database list because it needs to get time from server).

[image: two]

**Question**

How can I add time into my list items with some sort of delay? *(best if be possible to use `async/await`)*

**Update**

```
class WorldTime {

  String location; // location name for the UI
  String time; // the time in that location
  String flag; // url to an asset flag icon
  String country;
  String wikipedia;
  String name; // name of the location to get data from server
  bool isDaytime; // true or false if day time or not

  WorldTime({this.location, this.country, this.wikipedia, this.flag, this.name});

  Future<void> getTime() async {
      var apiUrl =  Uri.https('example.com', 'api/timezone', {'name': '$name'});
      // Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted response.
      var response = await http.get(apiUrl);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

        // get properties from data
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now().toUtc();
        String offset = jsonResponse['data']['offset'].substring(1, 3);// 07 (hour)
        String positive = jsonResponse['data']['offset'].substring(0, 1); // determine is positive or negative offset

        // create Datetime object
        String now1 = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').format(dateTime);
        DateTime now = DateTime.parse(now1);
        if(positive == '+') {
          now = now.add(
              Duration(
                  hours: int.parse(offset),
                  minutes: int.parse(jsonResponse['data']['offset'].substring(4, 6)) // 00 (minutes)
              )
          );
        } else {
          now = now.subtract(
              Duration(
                  hours: int.parse(offset),
                  minutes: int.parse(jsonResponse['data']['offset'].substring(4, 6)) // 00 (minutes)
              )
          );
        }

        print(now); //2021-05-25 09:57:08.000

        // set the time property
        isDaytime = now.hour > 5 && now.hour < 18 ? true : false;
        time = DateFormat.jm().format(now);
      } else {
        print('Request failed with error:  ${response.statusCode}.');
        isDaytime = false;
        time = 'Could not get time data';
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FutureBuilder for calling instance.getTime() since it returns a Future. Replace `Text('$time')` with following:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: instance.getTime(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && instance.time != null) {
      return Text(instance.time.toString());
    }
    return Text('No Data');
  },
),
```

Since `getTime` returns the `void` & assigns `time` to `WorldTime` instance, use `instance` inside the `if` condition.

Comment: thank you, but it only shows `No Data` will not update it to the time

Comment: It's possible that getTime is returning null. Can you post signature of `getTime()`? Is `instance` a Future?

Comment: Yes it's future, let me update my question for you

Comment: Edited my answer, this should fix your issue.

Comment: Still the same, I can see my times in console but in view just get `No Data`

Comment: I forgot to told you to remove `snapshot.data != null` & `snapshot.hasData`, it would be null in your case because getTime returns `void`. Updated my answer.